# Access SQL Issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

I am curious if there are any experts in Access' version of SQL that could help me decode the below?  I am not great in Access and try use SSMS but I am taking over an already built report.

Thanks!

```
LT CRD: IIf(Day(Date()+[IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME]) Between 1 And 15,DateSerial(Year(Date()+[IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME]),Month(Date()+[IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME]),15),DateSerial(Year(Date()+[IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME]),Month(Date()+[IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME])+1,0))
```

Comment: Access?  SSMS? What is your question at least?

Comment: I am trying to understand what that snippet of Access SQL (Jet SQL?) is trying to say.  I am not well versed in Access specific SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In words, the code is saying

*"If the current date + `[IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME]` results in a date in the first 15 days of a month, then return the 15th of that month; else, return the date of the last day of the month."*

For reference -

- `Date()`  returns the current date
- `Day()` returns the day part of a date, e.g. `Day(#2018-10-29#) = 29`
- `DateSerial()` returns a date given a year, month & day argument.
- `Year()` returns the year part of a date, e.g. `Year(#2018-10-29#) = 2018`
- `Month()` returns the month part of a date, e.g. `Month(#2018-10-29#) = 10`

Also note that `DateSerial(Year, Month, 0)` will return the last day in the previous month i.e. the day before `DateSerial(Year, Month, 1)`